# Measuring 2 Pi radians in a full rotation of MPU-6050, regardless of the pivot point

Tags: mpu6050, robotics, gyroscope

**The Project:**

I want to measure orientation of the MPU-6050 in z-axis for a mobile robot powered with the Arduino Mega 2560, so I need an accurate and reliable rotation measurement for the robot's movement.

I decided to use the gyroscope feature of the MPU-6050 sensor to measure orientation of its z-axis, by using its rotational velocity measurements.

I got the readings from Adafruit's MPU6050 library because it measures gyroscope using rad/s instead of raw data, so I can use the readings easily.

**The Implementation:**

I would really like to provide the source code with this question, but unfortunately while i'm writing this, I cannot get acces to the source code, and I will provide it as soon as I get access to it.

My implementation is, I used the z-axis velocity by dividing the current reading by 100 to get velocity per 10ms, then run a 10ms delay, and after that I add and assign the value to a variable (the += operator). And I run that in a loop.

The code might look something like this:

```
float currentReading;
float orientation = 0;

void loop() {
    
    g = doMpuReadings();
    currentReading = g.gyro.z / 100;

    delay(10);

    orientation += currentReading;
 }
```

For those who might wonder why I delayed the code by 10ms is to wait the sensor to travel a distance before defining its orientation.

The code worked quite like how I expected it to work. When I rotate it at some point, the orientation value adds, and when I rotate it back to its initial value, the orientation value goes back to near zero, and the values are pretty consistent.

**The Issue:**

But if I hold the sensor and rotate it by its center, it doesn't read 2 Pi or 6.28 rad, but it reads around 2 rad instead regardless of how fast or slow I rotate the sensor. When it is attached to the robot in which it doesn't rotate by its center, it reads around 5 rad. So like, the bigger circle it travels means more radians and vice versa?

Is that how it supposed to work?

Any possibilities to consistently measure 6.28 rad in a full rotation regardless of the pivot point?

Comment: I am not aware of any MEMS gyroscope that work with no offset or magnitude calibration. With out offset calibration you will drift (appear to be rotating) when not moving. Without magnitude calibration you will not measure the amount of rotation accurately.